# How to code enemies following player in ONLY HTML5/JS/Canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I am really new to coding, and I might have picked off a project that's bigger than I can chew....
I am trying to code an "avoider" game where the player moves the mouse around the screen in order to avoid the enemies following, or coming at the player. If the enemies touch the player-- game over.

So far, all the tutorials I've found that don't involve using Unity or some other game building software only have the enemies falling from the top of the screen-- not actually following the player around.

Is something like this even possible just using basic HTML5 and JS? Does anyone have any tips on where to start with this or any good tutorials or example code?

Thank you!

Comment: Sure, it's possible (many things are in programming), have you made any attempt at coding anything yet?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, this is possible in vanilla js. You may want to break down the problem. First you need to track the player's location. All you need are the x and y coordinates. Then you just increase the movement of the enemy towards those coordinates.

This tutorial does the opposite. The enemy avoids. It's also based on the mouse, but it should lead you in the right direction if you can't figure it out.

https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/html5-avoider-game-tutorial-multiple-moving-enemies--active-9956